# VBA send XMLHttpRequest from Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

tl;dr: How can one send a POST request in VBA by using an XMLHttpRequest within the Internet Explorer?

---

I'm about automating the use of page on the internet. The idea is to start from Excel to gather some data in a worksheet, then transfer these data to the internet page, click some buttons in the meantime, and thereafter work on manually.

I recorded the whole process when executed manually by the F12 Developer tools. By bringing the data into the textboxes of the internet page, some Javascript events take place which fire a POST request through XMLHttpRequest:
[image]

Now, by replicating the procedure described above in VBA (using `getElementById`, `.click()`,`.value=` and the like), it appears that the relevant events are not fired: no such POST request as shown above are sent to the server, and no additional masks open. This is why I wanted to omit the textbox-filling-and-clicking approach and simply replicate the POST request.

How can I do this from VBA by using the Internet Explorer?

Disclaimer: I'm aware how to send a POST request using `MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP`, which is described hundreds of times over the web. However, there it's always either-or: either use the Internet Explorer, or `MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP`. However, I need the request within the Internet Explorer.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without seeing the actual URL - there are many potential events which code in your HTML page could be responding to (blur, key down/up, focus, etc etc)

Comment: @TimWilliams: (i) is it possible to figure out the occuring events in a clever or systematic way? (--without trial and error with recording)  (ii) anyways, I don't want to use the event-reproduction way. I want to directly fire a post request using XMLHttpRequest in the Internet Explorer, and this from VBA ... so that the server sees the same result as it would otherwise be triggered by Javascript events.

Comment: Yes it's probably possible, but you will need to examine the page and figure out exactly what's going on there.

Comment: @TimWilliams: ok, thanks, that relates to (i). The heart of the OP is at (ii). Any ideas?

Comment: I was talking about both parts.  You need to figure out (i) in order to do (ii).

Comment: @TimWilliams: I did, and I exactly know the POST request I want to send --it's there in the F12 developer tools. I just don't know how to replicate it in the Internet Explorer using VBA.

Comment: Do you have access to the js code that is sending the POST ?

Comment: @RobertMackenzie: I can see it in the browser, yes. But it's quite much, quite unformatted and I don't know Javascript well. What would you suggest when the code is there? ... probably going through it and figure out exactly what is done, yes?

Answer (score 1):

These links looks promising |[VB5](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167658/how-to-automate-internet-explorer-to-post-form-data)| [C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815724/how-to-automate-internet-explorer-to-post-form-data-by-using-visual-c-.net-or-visual-c-2005) |
[Navigate method, 4th argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752093(v=vs.85).aspx) |[Another VB example using StrConv for byte array conversion](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_sendfrmie/)|
It looks like you simply use the Navigate method and simply data packed into a byte array for the fourth argument.  One of the above links is old but the newer link looks very similar so I think the interface has not changed much.

Do please post feedback.